# Looping Animation of Falling Particles in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: animation, particles, geometry-nodes, looping

I've been following Blender Guru's 3.0 Donut Tutorial and have been trying to figure out if there is a way to seamlessly loop the falling sprinkles made in Part 12. I've Googled for ways to make looping animations using Geometry Nodes in Blender and I have found some solutions using the particle system, but none that allow a looping animation specifically for falling particles in Geometry Nodes.

I'm trying to change the Geometry Node setup I made from this video to make a looping animation of petals falling to be used as a background for streaming. Is there a way to accomplish looping animations of falling particles in Geometry Nodes?

Picture of finished floating particle setup:
[image]

Blender Guru Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oA4maNXlIf0&list=PLjEaoINr3zgFX8ZsChQVQsuDSjEqdWMAD&index=12

Comment: I think this tutorial is what you're looking for - you can easily apply the methods in the video to sprinkles (rather than confetti) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Au0eLbCR1v0 - (He explains the gist of it at the 1 minute mark).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Tadaaa! Here I present you the **ultimate looped particle simulator 3000** for *Geometry Nodes*

Most video tutorials describe only the nesting/stacking of grids, when it comes to looped points in *geometry nodes*.

Often they are not really loops, but simply a stacking of points/planes on top of each other.
I want to change that now and present you a solution where you get a "real" infinite loop.

This is of course only possible because the duration of the animation (frames) depends on the change of positions and rotations.

The core of the matter is to create the same positions and rotations at the last frame as at the first frame. This is how I would describe a real loop.

Here is the result:

[image]

[image]

Unfortunately the node tree has become a bit big, I hope you forgive me.

[image]

I'll tweak a few things, but it should give you a good starting point for now.

*...and I will of course try to describe it all in more detail soon, but for now I have to leave.*

[image]

Comment: Thank so much for your help! I was able to use this node tree to make exactly what I wanted! :D